# Return value from a Java code

Tags: java, shell, unix, scripting, ksh

There is a Java class which creates a POST request and sends it to a servlet.
The main method of the class file (test) looks something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  // Code logic goes here...
  // No return Statement
}
```

This is called from a KornShell (ksh) script something like this:

```
retcode=`$CLK_JAVA_PATH -cp $CLASSPATH test ${PASSWORD} ${HOSTNAME} ${TOOLSET}`

if [ $? != "0" ];then
        echo "ERROR:  
        echo "${retcode}"
else
        echo "${SCRIPT} Success"
fi
```

`retcode` always has the value "2" independent of if the code fails or succeeds.
My question is since the return type of my main method is "void" why is the code returning some value?

Answer (score 53):

The return value of a Java application is **not** the return value of it's `main` method, because a Java application doesn't necessarily end when it's `main` method has finished execution.

Instead the JVM ends when no more non-daemon threads are running or when [`System.exit()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) is called.

And `System.exit()` is also the only way to specify the return value: the argument passed to `System.exit()` will be used as the return value of the JVM process on most OS.

So ending your `main()` method with this:

```
System.exit(0);
```

will ensure two things:

- that your Java application really exits when the end of `main` is reached and
- that the return value of the JVM process is 0

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it has a better explanation of the inner workings.

Comment: It is also worth noticing, that because of `System.exit()` placed in `try` or `catch` clause, the `finally` block will **not** be executed—so if one needs to perform some clean-up code, this should be taken into account.

Answer (score 18):

Java programs do not return an exit code back to the operating system by returning a value from `main`, as is done in C and C++. You can exit the program and specify the exit code by calling `System.exit(code);`, for example:

```
// Returns exit code 2 to the operating system
System.exit(2);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
System.exit(0);
```

This returns error code 0 (everything went fine).
[System.exit Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29)

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
System.exit( someNumber );
```

this will give your app control over the return value seen by the OS.

Answer (score 3):

Your program **always** returns a return code after exiting. In normal programs, if you do not specify a return code, it will return **zero** (this includes setting the return type to `void`).

Java, however, likes to be special! Java won't return the return code you return at the Main method, but it'll return some return code when the JVM exits (this accounts for multithreaded programs), and will return what a `System.Exit(returnCode);` call specifies.

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting the exit status, that's what `$?` contains. You're getting standard out, whatever is written to `System.out`.